# What is "top homology"?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

https://arxiv.org/abs/0711.1847v3

This paper discusses "the link of the origin" and its "top rational homology". I can't find any elucidating results by googling either of these phrases. What do they mean?

Comment: In the paper Theorem 2.5 it says explicitly what it means by only top rational homology.: "Then the link L of 0 ∈ A has only top reduced rational homology, i.e.,
H˜
i(L, Q) = 0 for i < dim L = dim X − 1. "
In this sort of context top means the maximal possible degree something non-trivial occurs in, for example a volume form is often called a top form, because you can't have any higher n-forms.

Comment: intro to links: https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/sdg/2013/0018/0001/SDG-2013-0018-0001-a004.pdf

Comment: thanks! I appreciate it